# How to execute Controller function in Angular after DOM element gets loaded in the view

Tags: angularjs

I want to execute function after DOM element gets loaded in the view..Actually, I want to calculate form progress on view load, my model pre-populate some form field and I want to immediately execute function to get the form progress. Currently, I tried this out but it fires early before the DOM elements gets loaded..Any suggestion?

```
$scope.$watch('$viewContentLoaded', function () {

            //my logic to calculate form progress
});
```

Comment: Try changing `$watch` to `$on`. I'm not sure $viewContentLoaded is what you're after, but `$watch` is for model changes and `$on` for events.

Comment: $on fires too early than $watch..Is there any better solution to execute function after model gets binded to dom elements?

Comment: it's the typical situation where you need a directive. Directive link function getting called after compilation

Comment: and where I need to put it on? As an attribute of fom tag?

Comment: It still get's called before the content of the form loaded..Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you provide a simple jsfiddle and explain a little more about what it is you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Actually, what I am trying to do is, I have a form which populated with some data if it is in edit mode. And I want to calculate the form progress weather it is in edit mode or add mode..In the edit mode what I am wondering is to initially call the function when the model values get binded to the DOM element. So, it get's the form progress.. I am using resolve function in route provider to slow load the page,so that, the function get executed after model values bind properly and also use directive which I put on form as an attribute to calculate the progress when it is loaded..